# form POST not working with huge json string; is there any other way to load a page with a huge amount of POST data?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, forms, post

I'm trying to use a form to load a page with Post data. The post data is an enormous string, and I'm not sure if the length is causing the problem.

I have a search page that directs to a results page, and the results page takes a while to load before showing the results. My client doesn't want the user to be directed away from the search page until the results have finished loading, because they don't like the lengthy "loading" spinner on the results page. The original structure of the site was that when the search button is clicked, it generates a querystring and uses window.location to direct to this action results, which returns a View:

```
public ActionResult Results(String q, String keywords, int? fromyear, int? toyear, int? newsearch, 
        String recordtype, String location, int? volumeId, string volumeName, string pageName, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes,
        bool favorites = false, bool free = false, bool images = false,
        String firstname = "", String lastname = "", bool soundex = false, bool exact = false, String category = "", 
        String database = "", String fam1first = "", String fam1last = "", String fam1type = "", String fam2first = "", 
        String fam2last = "", String fam2type = "", String fam3first = "", String fam3last = "", String fam3type = "", 
        int size = 50, int page = 1, String sortby = "Relevance", bool accessible = false, bool exactlocation = false, bool loadFirst = false)
    {
    .......
    return View("index", viewModel);
    }
```

I thought I might be able to accomplish this request by splitting the action into two parts: I can use Results to return the viewmodel as json, and then create a new actionresult that takes a json string, deserializes it into the viewmodel, and displays the viewmodel on the page:

```
public ActionResult LoadedResults(String jsonString = "")
{
    var vm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchResultsViewModel>(jsonString);
    return View("index", vm);
}
```

Now, on my search page, instead of navigating directly to a new URL, I do this:

```
var searchUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/SearchResults/Results?" + querystring;
$.ajax({
    url: searchUrl,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (info) {
        console.log(info);
        var results = JSON.stringify(info);
        $("#jsonString").val(results);
        $("#submitResults").click();
    },
    error: function (info) {
        alert("error");
    }
```

with this form:

```
<form id="resultsForm" method="POST" action="http://nehgs.mvc/SearchResults/LoadedResults">
    <input type="text" name="jsonString" id="jsonString"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitResults"/>
</form>
```

However, submitting the viewmodel string is leading to an error page with no information about what caused the error. I put a breakpoint on the first line of the LoadedResults actionresult. When I click the submit button with nothing in the text box, I hit the breakpoint. I also hit the breakpoint when I put in a dummy string, like "hello!", or empty json, like "{}". However, when I put in my actual viewmodel string, the breakpoint doesn't get hit, I just immediately get an error page.

Is this because my viewmodel string is too big? The string I'm testing with is 63088 characters, and it varies depending on the search. If this is the reason it's not working, is there any way that I can accomplish what my client is asking?

Comment: you are using `GET` in the ajax which has character length limits set by browsers, try using `POST`

Comment: The GET is used to generate the json string that is put into #jsonString. That part works. What doesn't work is clicking the submit button once the viewmodel data has been put in.

Comment: To be honest the process flow seems quite strange. Why do you need to send huge json from server just to put it in a form to submit it? WHy can't the data be stored in session at server or something similar

Comment: If you have a better idea for how to accomplish this, please say so. The client's request is unusual to me and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: Would look at why the results page takes a long time and see if it could be lazy loaded or paginated or something. Higher level problem isn't vey clear

Answer (score 0):

In your code use

```
$('#resultsForm').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
  type:"post",
  data:$(this).serialize(),
  success:function(response){
       //Your Code.
     }
  });
});
```

This will send the Form data using Post Method and you can load the result in the new page.